How do I create a continue numbering macro through all sections in Word 365?
I read a solution for automating continuous numbering through multiple sections (over 100).
It was to insert a macro, but I do not know how to do this. Can anyone show me how to take this action?
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Sections 
  With s.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers 
    .RestartNumberingAtSection = False 
    .StartingNumber = 0 
  End With 
Next s


A good place to start may be with doing a quick web search for how to create, edit, and run a macro in Word. Have you at least done that? How far did you get? Where did you have to stop?

See: http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm and http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html.
